# android Dialog: how to return Dialog after close an activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-dialog

I have a customized Dialog.  In this Dialog, there's one Button and one TextView.  When I click the button, I open a new activity.  This activity is a kind of file explorer written by myself.  I use a ListView to show the file name.  I want to close this activity when I click item of the ListView and return to the dialog.  I also want to write the item's title to the TextView in the Dialog.

Now I just don't know how to return to the Dialog?  I only know how to return to a new activity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to start the filemanager activity. After the user has chosen the file set a result with [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29). This allows you to fill a data bundle that is returned to the activity that startet the filemanager. Now [finish](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) the filemanager activity.

The activity that created the dialog will get the data bundle in [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29).

Comment: Thank you very much!  I know startActivityForResult.  But I just don't know how to use setResult, finish and onActivityResult.  Can you add some details of how to implement these methods?  I'm new in android.  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much.  Now I understand how these method working.